# How to create 18 digit timestamp in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, timestamp

How to create 18 digit timestamp in javascript?

Trying to send http headers to Facebook registration connect plugin which requires an 18 digit timestamp like: 265816695112975178

It is supposed to be current date-time reference.

Can anyone please help me build the code in Javascript preferably to create the timestamp? If not in JS then PHP please.

Thanks

Comment: What date is that timestamp meant to represent? It could be that you just need "milliseconds since the unix epoch" but it's not clear.

Comment: if gmp lib installed then

Comment: If you mean [this plug-in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/), I can't spot any 18-digit timestamp. They use regular ones like `1291840400` (Wed, 08 Dec 2010 20:33:20 GMT).

Answer (score 1):

Normally a timestamp of that magnitude indicates the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch (January 1st 1970, midnight UTC). EDIT: This doesn't actually give 18 digits... it gives 13 digits for "modern" timestamps.

Getting that in Javascript is easy, as that's the natural representation inside a `Date` object:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

The current value is about 1374818815000.

If that's *not* the intended semantics, you'll have to give more details (or link to documentation).

Comment: The OP wants 18 digits, ECMAScript uses IEEE 754 numbers that can't accurately represent a contiguous sequence of numbers with that many digits. Time values can only represent 8.64e15 ms either side of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, which is about 285,616 years, so probably sufficient for Facebook. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Eek, I'd forgotten about that - but actually it's nowhere near 18 digits.